# mysql_fetch_assoc overwrite array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following codewhich basically seems to be overwriting the same array each time so the output (json) only gives me the last row returned?

Thanks

```
$structure = mysql_query("SELECT FIELDNAME, DISPLAYNAME from `_PREFS_MAINGRID_`");
$rowsField = array();
while($struct = mysql_fetch_assoc($structure)) {
    $rowsField["columname"] = $struct;
}


$plode = implode("` as `", $rowsField["columname"]);

print json_encode($rowsField);
```

Answer (score 4):

You aren't pushing the elements into the array in your loop.

Try this:

```
$rowsField["columname"][] = $struct;
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/array_push) for more information.

Comment: That's great! Thank you, it works now... Yes I will check the documentation on that. How can I then implode on this? Thanks

Comment: @user2816451: The same way you did it before

Comment: $plode = implode("` as `", $rowsField["columname"]); seems to return the work "Array" as its an object when printing to the browser rather than the contents of the array? When I did it before I had `FIELDNAME as DISPLAYNAME` for example which is what I wanted,  for each row returned

Comment: @realtek: The command isn't exactly the same -- it needs modifications. `$rowsField` is now a multi-dimensional array. Try doing a `echo '<pre>,print_r($rowsField),'</pre>';` and see the what the array contains. And use the correct value in your `implode()`.

Comment: thats great thank you. I re-wrote this using a foreach loop at the moment until I can figure out the implode on it. the printing of the array helped a lot! Thank you

Comment: @realtek: Glad I could help. Please mark this answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking on the green checkmark if it answers your question :)